# What is the difference between Debug and Debug 1.0 within Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm wondering what is the difference between Debug and Debug 1.0 within Visual Studio 2008.

[image]

Is Debug 1.0 something new? I don't remember to see it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that "Debug 1.0 is a **[build configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa%28VS.90%29.aspx)**. Build configurations allow you to store different sets of project properties within a single solution.

By default, projects are created with a *Debug* and *Release* configuration, but you may add additional configurations with custom settings yourself.

Build configurations can differ considerably, but unfortunately there is no easy way of comparing/diffing two configurations. It's probably easiest to open the project files in a text editor and check for the textual differences.

Answer (score 0):

To see the difference between various solution configurations, click the 'Configuration Manager' item that's highlighted in the image you posted.

In the Configuration Manager, there is a drop down box labeled 'Active solution configuration'. Set it to 'Debug 1.0' and note down what appears in the 'Configuration' column (in the table at the bottom of the Configuration Manager). Usually, the item in the Configuration column will have the same name as the Active solution configuration. (This doesn't need to be true, though.)

Now open the Solution Explorer, right click on your project, and select Properties. In the window that opens, go to the 'Build' tab. From the 'Configuration' drop down box, select the Configuration that you noted down earlier.

The window now gives you an overview of all the settings for the configuration. Repeat the process again for 'Debug' instead of 'Debug 1.0', and see if anything is different.

Comment: How does this show the differences? This looks like simply viewing projects properties or am I missing something?

Comment: @0xA3: It *doesn't* show the differences. But that's something you read into the question, not what was actually asked. The questioner wants to know what the difference is, not necessarily to have a tool that shows him such. However, I have no idea what the difference is (no one does), therefore I'm providing a walkthrough that allows him to find out himself.